# How to create a list of a three sentence docstring with each element in the list being one sentence with its punctuation mark in Python?

Tags: python, list, loops, methods

I feel this is answer might be simple, but I need some help. I need to create a list of 3 sentences from a docstring of three sentences. I initially thought the split() method could be used, but the problem with using split is that I need to include all parts of each sentence. I need all spaces and punctuation, so my argument in split() can't be a punctuation mark or empty string from my understanding. Could you help me create a list with each element being one sentence? Here the code that I have so far:

````
sentence = ''
docstring = 'The rain in #Spain in 2019, rained "mainly" on the plain.\
There is a nice function to split a string into a list based on a given \
delimiter! Why do I try to do too much?'

for character in docstring:
    sentence += character
    if character == '.' or character == '?' or character == '!':
        sentencelist.append(sentence)```
````

Answer (score 2):

```
docstring = 'The rain in #Spain in 2019, rained "mainly" on the plain. There is a nice function to split a string into a list based on a given delimiter! Why do I try to do too much?'

sentencelist = re.split(r'(?<=[.!?])\s+', docstring)
print(sentencelist)
```

Instead of going character by character you can simply use regex for the purpose. And to retain those those the result we use positive lookbehind assertion in our regex.

```
Output:
['The rain in #Spain in 2019, rained "mainly" on the plain.', 'There is a nice function to split a string into a list based on a given delimiter!', 'Why do I try to do too much?']
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped me a lot, and I was able to figure out the other issue that I had too. I still have a quick question though. My professor does not want me to have lines that are longer than 80 characters, so I have to '\'  in  my docstring to go to the next line. My code is interpreting the '\' as punctuation. Do you know how I can stop it from doing that? This is the last thing I need help on. Thank you so much!!

Comment: I don't think that should be an issue but I can see one issue that is w.r.t to space. in the example you shared earlier there is no space post \. The slash as such wont be an issue as that signifies continuation and will be considered as a single string. But one has to maintain the spacing post that to. Like e.g. " plain.\
There" will be considered as " plain.There" as there is no spacing here. To counter it just remove \s  from regex from end. But then you will get issue with having an empty string and unwanted spaces in result.